# TypeError :getFlashMovie is not a function in jRecorder

Tags: javascript, jquery, jrecorder

I am using JRecorder to record voice on web page.When I play it in Firefox, it gives me following error:

```
TypeError: getFlashMovie(...).jStartRecording is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

getFlashMovie(jRecorderSettings['recorder_name']).jStartRecording(max_time);
```

Please Download Module from [here](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/index.html)!

Comment: Hi! After two years you solved this error?